# Read RSA Public Key from x509 Certificate Bytes in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, x509certificate, x509certificate2

In C#, I'm retrieving an RSA public key from a HTTP request and it gives me the key encoded in base64.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string rsaPublicKeyBase64 = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost:8000/getkey");
// rsaPublicKeyBase64 = LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0KTUlHZk1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTkFEQ0JpUUtCZ1FEdDAwcXQ2Zi9UUXdMQmVsVExRdVlXb05xSQoxbmRkcFpaOGh0WWs4d0NLbmFuRFJpWkJ1NVo5NnBNT01yNi84RS9JUzB0amV4WGdsVjh0WFlKK0NKc1lDUHhoCnBDUkduUW9rYkE2MnpOODVXNEROVUNMQ0cyMXlXcndscFhjSmxLYkY2dFhxdmd3TGRQb2RwZzUwY3RrWkI4R0UKbDBLS3VOV3JHZXRad045V0NRSURBUUFCCi0tLS0tRU5EIFBVQkxJQyBLRVktLS0tLQo=
```

I then decode the base 64 RSA public key.

```
byte[] rsaPublicKey = Convert.FromBase64String(rsaPublicKeyBase64);
/*
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDt00qt6f/TQwLBelTLQuYWoNqI
1nddpZZ8htYk8wCKnanDRiZBu5Z96pMOMr6/8E/IS0tjexXglV8tXYJ+CJsYCPxh
pCRGnQokbA62zN85W4DNUCLCG21yWrwlpXcJlKbF6tXqvgwLdPodpg50ctkZB8GE
l0KKuNWrGetZwN9WCQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
*/
```

My next step is to convert this `byte[]` containing my RSA public key certificate into type `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. I've found answers online, but none seem to work for me.

Here's what I currently have (which does not work).

```
string rsaPublicKeyFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
try {
    File.WriteAllBytes(rsaPublicKeyFile, rsaPublicKey);
    cert = new X509Certificate2(rsaPublicKeyFile);
} finally {
    File.Delete(rsaPublicKeyFile);
}
```

I receive an unhandled exception error shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Unhandled Exception Error]

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot find the requested object.
```

Comment: You don't need to create X509Certificate2 object. And you can't create it from just public key. You need to load the key directly to `PublicKey` object.

Comment: @Crypt32 Can you provide an example please

Comment: Here it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Crypt32 there is no example for that situation. link contains examples: how to work with certificates *.crt &  *.pfx files. but question about other type of data. 
If i am wrong could you provide more exact answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Crypt32, I managed to solve it by referencing the [PublicKey Class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey(v=vs.110).aspx)

**I wrote a function `GetCertificateFromBytes(byte[] cert)` which writes to a temporary file in order to read the certificate:**

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromBytes(byte[] cert) {
    string certFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    try {
        File.WriteAllBytes(certFile, cert);

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
            return certCollection[0];
        } finally {
            store.Close();
        }
    } finally {
        File.Delete(certFile);
    }
}
```

**Then to Encrypt:**

```
X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateFromBytes(rsaPublicKey);
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
byte[] encrypted = publicKeyProvider.Encrypt(data, false);
```

Comment: It is strange: you have get first certificate from your local storage, which is not related to that one which you have saved in file system.
it is working because  certificate is valid and has supported format. but it is not yours one, it is absolutely other one.

Unfortunately i didn't yet find good solution.

Comment: This is not correct: the certificate bytes are saved, but never read. The example goes on by loading the first certificate in the current user store.